# Conflict merge not taking into account merge changes on resolve using

Tags: tortoisegit

Steps to reproduce:

1. generate a conflict merge (eg: have changes in your branch and fetch+merge from master)
2. on conflict commit window, find your conflicted file, right click and open conflict resolution configured with external merge - results a 3-way merge having base, remote and local
3. merge your changes into local
4. in the conflict commit window, right click the conflicted file again and choose: resolve using mine

It is expected that the merge done into local to be placed on the conflicted file, however your merge is discarded and instead the original local is used. Same thing goes for remote/their

I'm on latest Tortoisegit 2.3.0.0
with git version 2.9.2.windows.1
OS: Windows 7 SP1

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong? Cause this used to work in tortoise svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Git and TortoiseGit (might) work differently than SVN. Choosing "resolve using mine" or "resolve using theirs" will use the full version of the file as on your branch resp. the merged branch's file. The versions are taken from the git index - here we have an inherently difference to SVN which has these versions in the filesystem only (`.mine` and the two `.r*` files).

After manually resolving merge conflicts with e.g. TortoiseGitMerge, you should use "Resolved" which clears the conflict state in the Git index and keeps the conflicted file (which should now be conflict free after 3-way merge).

Comment: Well, there is some inconsistency in the UI then. I can accept that the resolve using * works like that, but when attempting to resolve a conflict, the 3-way merge that tortoisegit itself starts up, has BASE, REMOTE and LOCAL. What's the point in doing that 3-way merge if there is no control over what gets into the final "resolved" file, from within the merge window or conflict resolution commit window? I mean that is the default action when you double click the conflict file, so definitely for the developers that action made sense. So if it's not a bug, how do I use it properly? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If use use the 3-way merge you just select "Resolved" afterwards (TortoiseGitMerge can automatically do this on save) and not resolve using *. Selecting resolved, removes the LOCAL, REMOTE and BASE file and clears the conflict state in git index.

Comment: Tortoisemerge seems to be "the problem". I'm not using tortoisemerge, I'm using an external merge, araxis in my case, but I am pretty sure the same problem happens with any. Basically, in tortoisemerge you have REMOTE, LOCAL and merged, which is the actual target file. With an external merge, you have, as I said, BASE, REMOTE and LOCAL. So the target file is nowhere in sight, as such not merged into. So the bug seems to be the way tortoisegit calls the external merge tool.

Comment: However, I would argue that the way tortoisegit is calling it's internal tortoisemerge is actually the problem, because in the merge operation I want to merge my changes into remote, basically, I need to see my LOCAL changes compared to BASE so I can merge them properly into REMOTE, *OR*, the other way around, merge REMOTE compared to BASE into LOCAL. Using the tortoisemerge, I only see the difference between LOCAL and REMOTE, but it is not clear what part of that change is from remote and what is from local. But this is just how I view it.

Comment: Bottom line, there is definitely a problem here, be it how tortoisegit calls the external merge tool, or how the conflict resolution was design/implemented.

Comment: Ok, now I understood you: The conflict process is inherently differenly in Git. Just look at the working tree after a conflict happened, there are not REMOTE, BASE and LOCAL files - all this information is in the index. TortoiseGit only creates those files for merge tools. - Resolve using * takes the information from the index.

Comment: How TortoiseGIt calls external merge tools is user configured: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-Merge

Comment: Thank you. Pretty important piece of missed information there :)